# Video Steganography in Python

Tags: python, opencv, codec, steganography

I'm working on video steganography. I wanted to embed data inside a video and extract it. I use frames to embed data. Problem is I have 5sec video file. When i divide the video into frames and embed data in one of the frames. while converting it back to video, it changes to 2secs stegano video. I used FPS from the original file. And also codec used is "XVID".

```
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture("originalfile.mp4")
print cap1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/%0d.png")
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('stego_video.avi', fourcc, cap1.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), (1280,720))
i=0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    i+=1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & i<132:
        i+=1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & i==132:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please explain me why I'm getting 2sec video. Also extraction of data from that particular frame is not possible. Did I miss the flow somewhere?

Comment: Are you supposed to be incrementing `i` twice for each frame? This looks like it does the work for only half the number of frames, so 5 / 2 ~ 2 sec.

Comment: Thanks. That helped!!